# apache httpd keep sending http requests to strange IPs

Tags: apache-2.2, security, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy, rewritecond

Recently I noticed my server keeps sending data to strange location "121.11.76.48" by `netstat -na` .

To find out what it is sending , I tried :

```
tcpdump -i eth0 host 121.11.76.48 -nnvvXSs 1514
```

And found it keeps sending HTTP requests to this location :

```
22:55:21.179353 IP (tos 0x0, ttl  64, id 26103, offset 0, flags [DF], proto: TCP (6), length: 296) 192.168.1.13.58155 > 121.11.76.48.80: P, cksum 0x880b (incorrect (-> 0xd884), 1904784743:1904784999(256) ack 915059568 win 46
    0x0000:  4500 0128 65f7 4000 4006 4ce8 c0a8 010d  E..(e.@.@.L.....
    0x0010:  790b 4c30 e32b 0050 7188 b567 368a b370  y.L0.+.Pq..g6..p
    0x0020:  5018 002e 880b 0000 4745 5420 2f20 4854  P.......GET./.HT
    0x0030:  5450 2f31 2e31 0d0a 486f 7374 3a20 0d0a  TP/1.1..Host:...
    0x0040:  4163 6365 7074 3a20 2a2f 2a0d 0a52 6566  Accept:.*/*..Ref
    0x0050:  6572 6572 3a20 6874 7470 3a2f 2f77 7777  erer:.http://www
    0x0060:  2e78 6264 796d 2e63 6f6d 2f69 6e64 6578  .xbdym.com/index
    0x0070:  2e61 7370 0d0a 4163 6365 7074 2d4c 616e  .asp..Accept-Lan
    0x0080:  6775 6167 653a 207a 682d 636e 0d0a 4163  guage:.zh-cn..Ac
    0x0090:  6365 7074 2d45 6e63 6f64 696e 673a 2067  cept-Encoding:.g
    0x00a0:  7a69 702c 2064 6566 6c61 7465 0d0a 5573  zip,.deflate..Us
    0x00b0:  6572 2d41 6765 6e74 3a20 4d6f 7a69 6c6c  er-Agent:.Mozill
    0x00c0:  612f 342e 3020 2863 6f6d 7061 7469 626c  a/4.0.(compatibl
    0x00d0:  653b 204d 5349 4520 362e 303b 2057 696e  e;.MSIE.6.0;.Win
    0x00e0:  646f 7773 2035 2e31 290d 0a50 7261 676d  dows.5.1)..Pragm
    0x00f0:  613a 206e 6f2d 6361 6368 650d 0a56 6961  a:.no-cache..Via
```

Apparently , something in my server keeps sending packets (about one packet/sec) to www.xbdym.com (which is 121.11.76.48) , with IE6 browser !

But , my box is a linux box (CentOS 5.6) , there's no way to run IE6 on it. And I don't have any Windows VM installed.

Then , I use `lsof -i` to find what process sends the packet!

```
httpd   13232 apache   20u  IPv4 326404481       TCP 192.168.1.13:48988->121.11.76.48:http (ESTABLISHED)
```

It is apache ! It's weird , why apache sends packets to this location so frequently ?

I then dig into apache's log and find a lot of records in access_log :

```
121.11.80.126 - - [23/Dec/2011:22:58:58 +0800] "GET http://www.xbdym.com HTTP/1.1" 502 495 "http://www.xbdym.com/index.asp"
 "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows 5.1)"
```

and in rewrite.log :

```
121.11.80.126 - - [23/Dec/2011:23:05:57 +0800] [www.xbdym.com/sid#2b1de9435be0][rid#2b1df49d6ad0/initial] (1) pass through proxy:http://www.xbdym.com
```

Does my server behave as a proxy ?
In fact , directly connecting to my server is redirected to my inner java server (set by ProxyPass and ProxyPassReserve) , and I set this :

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myserver.com
RewriteLog "/home/myserver/log/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 1
```

There is a "`RewriteCond`" there , host not starting with 'myserver.com' should not pass !
But how it passes through my proxy !? And , how to stop it !?

Environments :

```
httpd-2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3
CentOS 5.6
2.6.18-238.12.1.el5xen
```

-- updated --

my ProxyPass settings :

```
ProxyPreserveHost on
ProxyPass        /app http://localhost:8080/app
ProxyPassReverse /app http://localhost:8080/app
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `RewriteCond` line only affects the next `RewriteRule` that is processed.  It does nothing on its own.

Since there is no `RewriteRule` following it in the snippet of your config you have given us, my best guess is that the `RewriteCond` is doing nothing.

A quick change that should block anything not sending the correct `Host:` header:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^myserver.com
RewriteRule - - [F]
```

Your analysis of what you have seen seems to be correct to me; your Apache is configured as an open relay.

What do your ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse lines look like ?  (I presume you actually wrote ProxyPassReverse in your Apache config and not ProxyPassReserve.)

I noticed the request sent an empty `Host:` header which is very strange.  I suspect your VirtualHost is configured as the default, meaning that it will process all requests, even if the `Host:` header does not match the `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` variables.

There is some advice on how to add an extra, non-proxying default VirtualHost in the [Apache wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ProxyAbuse).  And, for completeness, here's a link to the [mod_proxy documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html).

Comment: Hi , I've added my 'ProxyPassReverse and ProxyPass' settings. And it's true , my virtualHost is configured as the default.

Comment: Having never actually used Apache as a forward proxy, I just had a read through that part of the docs.  I now suspect you have `ProxyRequests On` somewhere in your configuration.  For a reverse proxy, this should be `ProxyRequests Off`.

Comment: Thanks , the Apache wiki ( http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ProxyAbuse ) seems helps me. At least , it's not attacked for 20 mins... :)